# Ruby executable in YAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml

I have a sample `yaml` file(`abc.yaml`) like this:

```
entity1:
  condition: "created_at >= #{Date.today - 3.months}"
```

I want to read this condition from `YAML` in Ruby as :

```
"created_at >= 2015-03-02"
```

But when I do

```
YAML.load_file('abc.yaml')["entity1"]["condition"]
```

I get:

```
"created_at >= \#{Date.today - 3.months}"
```

Please let me know how to work around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this only if you're absolutely sure nobody can change your yaml file to inject something harmful:

```
condition = YAML.load_file('abc.yaml')["entity1"]["condition"]
condition = eval "\"#{condition}\""
```

Comment: OP: I can't stress strongly enough the "only if you're absolutely sure" part; this is very very likely the wrong thing to do. If at all possible, refactor into something more restrictive.

Comment: `eval condition` will try to run `created_at >= \#{Date.today - 3.months}` and fail with syntax error. `condition = eval "\"#{condition}\""` will run `"created_at >= #{Date.today - 3.months}"` and generate `"created_at >= 2015-03-02"` string as a result.

Comment: Oh right sorry. Overlooked the interpolation. Then you probably need to follow it up with `eval eval "\"#{condition}\""`...

Answer (score 2):

The safer option would be to only convert known data from a pre-determined format. Or use something cool like settingslogic https://github.com/settingslogic/settingslogic. It uses ERB-style formatting to load settings, so you get some built in safety.

eg:

```
defaults: &defaults
  cool:
    saweet: nested settings
  neat_setting: 24
  awesome_setting: <%= "Did you know 5 + 5 = #{5 + 5}?" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use it like

```
entity1:
  condition: "created_at >= <%= Date.today - 3.months %>"
```

And while reading load it like

```
abc = YAML.load(ERB.new(File.read("file_path")).result)
abc["entity1"]["condition"]
```